# Which profile can view encrypted fields by default?

Tags: fields

i faced this question in 401 certification exam.
Please tell me the correct answer for this?
Which profile can view encrypted fields by default ?

Comment: Did you clear you 401?

Answer (score 10):

```
By Default no profile can see Encrypted Data.
```

Only those profile which has “View Encrypted Data” permission can see encrypted fields and by default this permission is not given to any profile. You have to active this permission in profile by checking “View Encrypted Data” check box .

For more detail See this link [Encrypted Field Details](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official document confirming only profile that has **view encrypted** field has permission to view

https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/fields_about_encrypted_fields.htm

There is a blog from force guru also helpful as reference on this topic

http://forceguru.blogspot.in/2011/05/encrypted-fields.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess there's no profile  in salesforce which has "View Encrypted Data" permission active by default.Even System Admin profile doesn't have it active by default.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the group! I would agree with you and with Pramod Kumar before you that no profile has it by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right. We don't find this option even with admin profile. Since we can't do any modifications to standard profiles we can clone the admin profile and change the permissions in cloned one. This is one way.